# Getting TypeError when inserting data to database

Tags: python, mysql, typeerror

First I extracted a list of colleges from a college website in the form of tuple of tuples:

*(('name1', 'address1'), ('name2', 'address2'), ('name3', 'address3'))*

then I want to write this is in a database named 'sample' and in table 'collegelist'. Table has two fields (name varchar(400) not null, address varchar(500)):

Here is the code:

```
for college in tuples:
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO collegelist (name, address) VALUES ("%s", "%s")') %(college[0], college[1])
   db.commit()
db.close()
```

But it always give following TypeError:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'tuple'
```

I also tried inserting only names and leaving addresses then I get following type Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'str'
```

Now i don't understand from where 'long' type came. There are only strings and tuples in the program.

> **Note**: Names and addresses of colleges have single quotes, double quotes, dash, period.

Why is this error coming and how can I remove it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute('INSERT INTO collegelist (name, address) VALUES ("%s", "%s")') <--`

At that point, you have closed the call to `execute`. Also, you should pass the arguments to `execute`, and never, ever, EVER parse them into the query.

```
q_insert = "INSERT INTO collegelist (name,address) VALUES (%s,%s)"
for college in tuples:
    cursor.execute(q_insert,(college[0], college[1]))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Passing parameter values to execute() helps prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), because escape characters are interpreted as part of the value, and cannot influence the query involved.